# Subgaussian Absolute Constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I  am looking at the proofs of equivalent properties for subgaussian random variables. Two listed below:

$$P(|X|\ge t)\le 2\text{exp}(\frac{-t^2}{K_1^2})$$

$$(\mathbb{E}|X|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\le K_2\sqrt{p}$$

I am able to follow the proofs but the constants $K_i$ are stated to differ only by an absolute constant.
According to the definition they propose that if $i$ implies $j$ then $K_j\le C K_i$ where $C$ is an absolute constant. Does this means that $C$ is the same for any $(i,j)$ pairing? Looking at the proofs that doesn't seem to be true. Can someone help clarify what they mean by absolute constant?

Comment: Which proof are you looking at?

Comment: The ones in High-Dimensional Probability: An Introduction with Applications in Data Science

Answer (score 1):

There are only finitely many pairs, so $C$ can be taken to be a number larger than any of the values that appear in each part of the proof of [Prop. 2.5.2](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf).

Comment: when the proof states that by homogeneity and rescaling of X that we can assume K=1 for the first statement what does this imply?

Comment: It means that instead of the $K_2=3$ obtained in the proof, the second constant will be $K_2=3K_1$. Basically, this is saying "apply the proof to $X'=X/K_1$ instead of $X$" (you can check that all conditions are homogeneous, i.e., that using $aX$ instead of $X$ in the proofs just changes the constants obtained by a factor $a$).